# How do I format an HyperLinkField

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have tried about everything I can think of. If anyone can help I would greatly appreciate it. 
My code:

```
 <asp:HyperLinkField
           DataNavigateUrlFields= "PONumber" 
           DataNavigateUrlFormatString= 
                 "../PurchaseOrder/PurchaseOrderInsert.aspx?PurchaseOrderID={0}"
           DataTextField="Description"
           HeaderText="Description"
           SortExpression="Description" />
```

I have even switched `DataNavigateFormatString` to `NavigateUrl` and still nothing. I really just need to this to navigate to a page and on that page is a link to navigate back.

Comment: What is happening in output as a result of this html? Please provide some more details

Answer (score 0):

Your markup seems correct. Its not very clear from your question that what is not working. 
Assuming that it is inside some Gridview type control.

But from the markup, it seems like you might want to use `~` instead of `../` to navigate to correct url.

```
 <asp:HyperLinkField
       DataNavigateUrlFields= "PONumber" 
       DataNavigateUrlFormatString= 
                 "~/PurchaseOrder/PurchaseOrderInsert.aspx?PurchaseOrderID={0}"
       DataTextField="Description"
       HeaderText="Description"
       SortExpression="Description" />
```

You could try msdn too. [HyperLinkField](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlinkfield(v=vs.110).aspx)